# Update one value in array of dicts, using jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to update a value in a dict, which I can only identify by another value in the dict. That is, given this input:

```
[
  {
    "format": "geojson",
    "id": "foo"
  },
  {
    "format": "geojson",
    "id": "bar"
  },
  {
    "format": "zip",
    "id": "baz"
  }
]
```

I want to change `baz`'s accompanying format to 'csv':

```
[
  {
    "format": "geojson",
    "id": "foo"
  },
  {
    "format": "geojson",
    "id": "bar"
  },
  {
    "format": "csv",
    "id": "baz"
  }
]
```

I have found that this works:

```
jq 'map(if .id=="baz" then .format="csv" else . end)' my.json
```

But this seems rather verbose, so I wonder if there is a more elegant way to express this. jq seems to be missing some kind of expression selector, the equivalent of might be `[@id='baz']` in xpath.

(When I started this question, I had `[.[] |...]`, then I discovered `map`, so it's not quite as bad as I thought.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A complex assignment is what you're looking for:

```
jq '(.[] | select(.id == "baz") | .format) |= "csv"' my.json
```

Perhaps not shorter but it is more elegant, as requested. See the last section of the docs at: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment

Edit: using `map`:

```
jq 'map((select(.id == "baz") | .format) |= "csv")' my.json
```

Comment: Ah ha. I notice that there's a superfluous pipe (I think). So it could be: `jq '(.[] | select(.id == "baz") .format) |= "csv"' my.json`

Comment: Another variation: `map(select(.id == "corangamite").format |= "csv")`

Comment: yeah, good one; I've added a variant using `map`; I'm not sure about the notation with the omitted pipe