# Modify one value in array

Tags: arrays, json, edit, jq

This is VERY similar to [Update one value in array of dicts, using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772676/update-one-value-in-array-of-dicts-using-jq)

I have a foo.json and I want to update AAA to AAA-MY-SUFFIX.
Basically, I want to get the current value (AAA), and then add a suffix to it.

`[
  {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "awesome"
  },
  {
    "Key": "role",
    "Value": "AAA"
  }
]`

From the previous question, I can REPLACE the value of AAA using this:

```
cat foo.json | jq '(.[] | select(.Key == "role") | .Value) |= "-MY_SUFFIX"'
```

But I want to APPEND a suffix to the existing value, not completely replace it.

Something like this (but it doesn't work, of course):

```
cat tags.json | jq '(.[] | select(.Key == "role") | .Value) |= .Value + "-MY_SUFFIX"'
```

I feel I'm SO close, but I just can figure it out :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close indeed.  You could simply replace `.Value + "-MY_SUFFIX"` by

```
. + "-MY_SUFFIX"
```

Or better yet, use `+=`, as in:  `... += "-MY_SUFFIX"`

Personally, I'd use the filter:

```
map(if .Key == "role" then .Value += "-MY_SUFFIX" else . end)
```

(Actually, the stated requirements would accord better with using the suffix `"-MY-SUFFIX"` :-)

Answer (score 1):

After much fooling around, I think I got it:

```
cat tags.json | jq '(.[] | select(.Key == "role") | .Value) |= (. + "- MY_SUFFIX")'
```