# Adding Element to array of element in json using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Ok, i spent way to much time on this.
Using jq, i want to test if an element exist in an array, if yes being able to mofify this element, if not adding this element to that array

I have read

- [Update one value in array of dicts, using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772676/update-one-value-in-array-of-dicts-using-jq)
- [How to check if element exists in array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259563/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-array-with-jq)

Which gave hints But i am stuck

Let say i have a json file like :

```json
    {
    "LOGIN":"user",
    "COPY": [
        {
            "CHAINLIST":"chain1",
            "ELEMENT": [ "element1-1","element1-2" ] 
        },
        {
            "CHAINLIST":"chain2",
            "ELEMENT": [ "element2-1","element2-2" ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I Would like to add elements to the COPY array based in the *CHAINLIST* id  , let say those 3 elements :

```json
//ELEM A
{
       "CHAINLIST":"chain3",
       "ELEMENT": [ "element3-1" ] 
    }
//ELEM B
    {
       "CHAINLIST":"chain2",
       "ELEMENT": [ "element2-1","element2-3" ] 
    }
//ELEM C
    {
       "CHAINLIST":"chain1",
       "ELEMENT": [ "element1-1","element1-2" ] 
    }
```

**ELEM A**  has the *CHAINLIST* id chain3 who doesn't exit in the **COPY** Array _> let's add it

**ELEM B** Is already present in the **COPY** aray, I want to update the **ELEMENT**  array
content  with the new value

**ELEM C** Already exist and is up to date, i don't need to do anything.

In my example the final json object would be

```json
    {
    "LOGIN":"user",
    "COPY": [
        {
            "CHAINLIST":"chain1",
            "ELEMENT": [ "element1-1","element1-2" ] 
        },
        {
            "CHAINLIST":"chain2",
            "ELEMENT": [ "element2-1","element2-2","element2-3" ] 
        },
        {
            "CHAINLIST":"chain3",
            "ELEMENT": [ "element3-1"] 
        }
     ]
    }
```

I am using jq The procedure to add the element Elem to the object Obj  would be :

Elem.CHAINLIST exist in Obj.COPY [] ?

yes : add Elem.ELEMENT to Obj.ELEMENT[] with unique to qvoid duplicates

no : add Elem to Obj.COPY[]

The best i get is

```
    (if .COPY[]? | select (.CHAINLIST=="chain3") == "" then . else .COPY[.COPY | length ] |= . + { "CHAINLIST":"chain3","ELEMENT":[ "element3-1"]}  end )
```

But `select (.CHAINLIST=="chain3") == ""`  return nothing I i can figure out how to test if empty.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses the built-in function `INDEX/2` to create convenient and efficient representations
of the collections of CHAINLIST-ELEMENT objects, together with a bespoke function, `augment/1`, for combining elements.

It is assumed that the objects defining the updates are presented as an array in the file `edits.json`.

```
< input.json jq --argfile edits edits.json '

  # Use `unique` to combine the .ELEMENT fields
  def augment($b):
     reduce ($b|keys_unsorted[]) as $key (.; 
       .[$key].ELEMENT = (.[$key].ELEMENT + $b[$key].ELEMENT | unique));

  (INDEX($edits[];.CHAINLIST) | map_values(del(.CHAINLIST))) as $edits
  | (INDEX(.COPY[]; .CHAINLIST) | map_values(del(.CHAINLIST))) as $COPY
  | .COPY |= ($COPY
              | augment($edits)
              | to_entries
              | map( { CHAINLIST: .key, ELEMENT: .value.ELEMENT} ))
```

Output: as specified in the question.

Note: if the objects defining the updates are presented as a sequence of objects in a file, you could use the above solution with `--slurpfile` instead of `--argfile`.